# Undefined control sequence in algorithm package

Tags: ubuntu, algorithm2e

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 with TeXmaker and TeX Live. There is a `\newenvironment` definition in my LaTeX file:

```
\newenvironment{algo}[1]{%
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]
    \SetTitleSty{textsc}{normalsize}
    \SetInd{0.25em}{0.25em}
    \SetAlgoVlined
    \SetNlSty{normal}{}{}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwComment{tcp}{}{}
    \small
  }{%
    \vspace{-0.5ex}
  \end{algorithm}
}
```

And the use is something like

```
\begin{algo}{t}
...
\end{algo}
```

which gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\algo ... \SetInd {0.25em}{0.25em} \SetAlgoVlined 
                                                  \SetNlSty {normal}{}{} \Do...
```

The file compiles well on Windows 7 + MikTeX.

Anybody else facing similar problems on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

You might have an old version of the algorithm2e package -- I know mine's from the ubuntu repos texlive distro, and I have to use `\dontprintsemicolon` instead of the capitalized version.

You can either find out whether there are old analogues for the commands you're trying to use, update the algorithm2e package on your local tex distribution, or provide a copy of the latest algorithm2e.sty in the directory where it's being compiled.

Edit: in case you do have an old version (which you probably do, with the texlive from ubuntu repos), here's the corresponding commands:

- `\SetAlgoVlined` is `\SetVline`
- As mentioned, `\DontPrintSemicolon` is `\dontprintsemicolon`

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 still contains TeX Live 2009. If you want to use versions of packages that are newer than what came with TL2009, you should install directly from [TUG](http://tug.org/texlive/) instead of using the Debian/Ubuntu packages.

Comment: and @Caramdir
Thanks for your help!
I tried to do what TJ said, namely using the older commands but that did not work as it gave me some other errors. So I installed Texlive 2010 and now it works smoothly! Sorry I did not reply earlier, took some time for me to install the new version of Texlive.

Comment: @Nilesh glad you got it working!

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, you might want your code to be compatible with both versions of the package. In that case, one possibility is to use the `\providecommand` as follows:

```
\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}
\providecommand{\SetAlgoLined}{\SetLine}
\providecommand{\DontPrintSemicolon}{\dontprintsemicolon}
[...]
```

After that, the use of `\SetAlgoLined` and `\DontPrintSemicolon` should consistently do the job.

Comment: Or, by example, \providecommand{\SetLine}{\SetAlgoLined}, etc.,  if you have old code and a new version of algorithm2e